# How to fix Error The type 'object' cannot be used as type parameter 'TToken' in the generic type or method?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, maui, messagingcenter

I'm doing a migration to .NET MAUI from Xamarin Forms. Here I am converting the **MessagingCenter** of **Xamarin Forms** to **WeakReferenceManager** of **.NET MAUI**. This is my Following code of **Xamarin Forms**:

```
MessagingCenter.Subscribe<object, object>(this, Messages.Messenger.Messages.xyz, this.XYZ);
```

This code is working fine for me. But when I am converting this to **WeakReferenceManager** as you can see the following:

```
WeakReferenceMessenger.Default.Register<object, object>(this, Messages.Messenger.Messages.xyz, this.XYZ);
```

I get the following error:

**Error CS0311 The type 'object' cannot be used as type parameter 'TToken' in the generic type or method 'IMessengerExtensions.Register<TMessage, TToken>(IMessenger, object, TToken, MessageHandler<object, TMessage>)'. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'object' to 'System.IEquatable'.**

I have no clue how to fix this error. Any suggestions?

Comment: Error actually tells you everything. You are trying to Register with type `object` while your method requires object which implements `IEquatable` interface.

Answer (score 1):

You can refer to the official document: [Sending and receiving messages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/mvvm/messenger).

Please refer to the following code:

```
 // Create a message (e.g. `MyMessage`) you want to pass in your app
public class MyMessage : ValueChangedMessage<string>
{
    public MyMessage(string value): base(value)
    {        
    }
}

// Register a message where you want to receive message
WeakReferenceMessenger.Default.Register<MyMessage>(this, (r, m) =>
{
    // Handle the message here, with r being the recipient and m being the
    // input message. Using the recipient passed as input makes it so that
    // the lambda expression doesn't capture "this", improving performance.

      var receivedstring = m.value;
});

// Send a message
WeakReferenceMessenger.Default.Send(new MyMessage("test string"));
```

**Note:**

You can also replace the passed `string` to Object item you want to pass.

Here is a usage example:

1.define a message
(The `TestVisibleModel` is the type of the passed object)

```
 public class VisibleChangedMessage : ValueChangedMessage<TestVisibleModel> 
{
    public VisibleChangedMessage(TestVisibleModel value) : base(value)
    {

    }
}
```

2.Register a message:

```
   TestVisibleModel  visibleModel = new TestVisibleModel();

    // Register a message in some module
    WeakReferenceMessenger.Default.Register<VisibleChangedMessage>(this, (r, m) =>
    {
        //receive the message here
        visibleModel.IsVisible1 = m.Value.IsVisible1;

    });
```

3.Send message:

```
    TestVisibleModel model = new TestVisibleModel();
    model.IsVisible1 = false;

    // Send a message from some other module
    WeakReferenceMessenger.Default.Send(new VisibleChangedMessage(model));
```

Comment: Hi @Judson, may I know whether your issue has been solved or not? If not, please share it in here. We can work together to figure it out.